# Magento order quantity shown in paypal as x 1 with real quantity in item name

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, quantity

Paypal is showing some line items as quantity x 1 and the real quantity is then displayed in the item name, for example;

Qty   Item                                Price

**1** Noro Silk Garden Chunky 10 **x10**  £49.59 GBP

I beleive this comes from: `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Cart.php`

Workaround in case if item subtotal precision is not compatible with PayPal (.2)

```
$subAggregatedLabel = ‘’; 
if ($amount - round($amount, 2)) { 
    $amount = $amount * $qty; 
    $subAggregatedLabel = ‘ x’ . $qty; 
    $qty = 1;
}
```

How can I get the quantity to show in the correct field Qty and not the Item?

Comment: Which version of Magento?

Comment: Hi benmarks, Magento version 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused when my product price was converted from our base currency to US $. Since Magento stores 3 values after the decimal point, this was causing a 1 cent difference in the prices when it goes through PayPal condition in Cart.php

The solution which worked for us was to round off the $amount to 2 decimal place before the condition starts(above $subAggregatedLabel = ‘’;)

This would mean that PayPal's conditions are bypassed and the right order details show up on the PayPal payment page.

Comment: Thank-you for this contribution! If we round off to 2 decimal place will this effect the VAT calculations. How exactly do you round off before the condition? Do you just move the if ($amount - round($amount, 2)) above the $subAggregatedLabel = ‘’;

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has come across this similar PayPal Qty 1 issue, I think this thread is the most concise in explaining the issue so I have therefore added a link to some code that I found which was seemingly a patch for EE which has solved has the issue for a client of mine but which was never patched for CE as far as I'm aware.

https://gist.github.com/pkdavies/4681728